# How is NullPointerException in Java 14 different from its predecessor?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-14

One of the important features that were introduced with Java SE 14 was the **[Helpful NullPointerExceptions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/14-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8218628)** which is related to the usability of the `NullPointerException`. What makes `NullPointerException` in Java SE 14 more usable than its predecessor?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404681/8967612).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The JVM throws a `NullPointerException` at the point in a program where code tries to dereference a `null` reference. With Java SE 14, the `NullPointerException` offers helpful information about the premature termination of a program.  Java SE 14 onwards, the JVM describes the variable (in terms of source code) with a *null-detail message* in the `NullPointerException`. It greatly improves program understanding by more clearly associating a dynamic exception with static program code.

We can see the difference with an example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Price {
    double basePrice;
    double tax;

    public Price() {
    }

    public Price(double basePrice) {
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
    }

    public Price(double basePrice, double tax) {
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
        this.tax = tax;
    }
    // ...
}

class Product {
    String name;
    Price price;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, Price price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    // ...
}

class CartEntry {
    Product product;
    int quantity;

    public CartEntry() {
    }

    public CartEntry(Product product, int quantity) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    // ...
}

class Cart {
    String id;
    List<CartEntry> cartEntries;

    public Cart() {
        cartEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Cart(String id) {
        this();
        this.id = id;
    }

    void addToCart(CartEntry entry) {
        cartEntries.add(entry);
    }
    // ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cart cart = new Cart("XYZ123");
        cart.addToCart(new CartEntry());
        System.out.println(cart.cartEntries.get(0).product.price.basePrice);
    }
}
```

### Output before Java SE 14:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

This message leaves the programmer clueless about the source of the `NullPointerException`.

### The output with Java SE 14 onwards:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "price" because "java.util.List.get(int).product" is null
    at Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

The `NullPointerException` in Java SE 14 also tells us **which reference is `null`**.

**A great improvement!**

Comment: The "premature termination" isn't relevant. The information is still there if you catch it instead.

Comment: It is vague and inaccurate to imply that exceptions cause "premature termination of the program". Yes, *uncaught* exceptions cause the *thread* to complete abruptly, but that only terminates the program if it was the last non-daemon thread alive. And even if the program chooses to terminate, this doesn't imply a lack of maturity.

Comment: Oh, and *objects* can't be null. Only *references* can be.

Comment: This is a nice answer and could be complemented with the infor from the other ones related to newer java versions.

Answer (score 45):

It is documented in the release notes.

The new message is not being displayed by default in version 1.14:

[What's new in JDK 14](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/14-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8218628)

> A new option is available to provide more helpful NullPointerException messages:
>
> -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
>
> If the option is set, on encountering a null pointer, the JVM analyzes the program to determine which reference was null and then provides the details as part of NullPointerException.getMessage(). In addition to the exception message, the method, filename, and line number are also returned.
>
> **By default, this option is disabled.**

and the full proposal [JEP 358](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358) for motivation.

Eventually

[What's new in JDK 15](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8233014)

> The default of the flag ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages was changed to 'true'.

Answer (score 9):

When the JVM throws a `NullPointerException`, it now adds a detail message that specifies which reference was null.

This makes the stack trace easier to interpret, and resolves ambiguity if the program accesses several references on the same line in the source code. For instance, the line

```
person.name = student.name;
```

throws a `NullPointerException` if `person` or `student` is `null`, but prior to Java 14, the exception didn't tell us which one it was. Now, it does:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "name" because "student" is null

Further information about this change is available in [JEP-358](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358).